# Call Azure SignalR Service Hub method(Server less method) from ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application where I have already implemented Signalr using ASP.NET SignalR V2. But now I need to integrate the Azure SignalR Service as well using the Server less method.

I searched lot of documentation, but I cannot find a correct way of calling the Hub method or connecting to Azure signalr Service. Please find the code what I tried so far

```
private static async void PushNotification(NotificationRequest notificationRequest, NotificationResponse notificationResponse, string signalRUrl, string authenticationType, Cookie cookie, ICredentials credentials, string accessToken, string userId, string cacheString)
    {
        if (authenticationType == "AzureSignalR")
        {
            HubConnection _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(signalRUrl).Build();
        }
        else
        {
            using (var hubConnection = new HubConnection(signalRUrl))
            {
                IHubProxy notificationHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");
                if (authenticationType != "AzureSignalR")
                {
                    ConfigureHubConnection(hubConnection, authenticationType, cookie, credentials);
                }

                try
                {
                    await hubConnection.Start();
                    await notificationHubProxy.Invoke("Send", notificationRequest, notificationResponse);
                    hubConnection.Stop();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (hubConnection != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hubConnection.ConnectionId))
                    {
                        hubConnection.Stop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Here I am getting error on HubConnectionBuilder.WithUrl(), showing as WithURL() doesnot exists in library. I referenced the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.

And this is my hub class derived inside Azure Function app.

```
public class NotificationHub : ServerlessHub
{
    [FunctionName("index")]
    public static IActionResult GetHomePage([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "content", "index.html");
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = File.ReadAllText(path),
            ContentType = "text/html",
        };
    }

    //[FunctionName("negotiate")]
    //public SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req)
    //{
    //    return Negotiate(req.Headers["x-ms-signalr-user-id"]);
    //}

    [FunctionName("negotiate")]
    public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
       [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req,
       [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "NotificationHub")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
    {
        return connectionInfo;
    }
    [Authorize]
    [FunctionName(nameof(Send))]
    public async Task Send([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, NotificationRequest notificationRequest, NotificationResponse notificationResponse)
    {
        try
        {
            await Clients.Clients(notificationResponse.ConnectionIds).SendAsync("SendNotification", notificationRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    [FunctionName(nameof(OnDisconnected))]
    public async Task OnDisconnected([SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext, ILogger logger)
    {
        var response = await APIService.CallDisconnectedTrigger(invocationContext.ConnectionId);
        if (response != null && response.ErrorMessages.Any())
        {
            string errorMessages = string.Join(", ", response.ErrorMessages);
            logger.LogInformation("Some error occured while disconnecting SignalR Connection. " + errorMessages);
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone please provide the code for connecting with Azure SignalR service from ASP.NET MVC Application?

Answer (score 0):

I have Installed the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core` NuGet Package.

I have tried to add your code, Initially Even I got the same error.

[image]

> I referenced the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.

Even I have added the reference.

To get `WithUrl`, we need to Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` NuGet Package separately.

[image]

Now Iam able to add the `WithUrl`.

[image]

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="7.0.10" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core" Version="7.0.10" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

The code which you have configured seems to be correct.

Found this Blog which has examples for [ASP.NET](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/azure-signalr-service-now-supports-asp-net/) and [MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/AzureSignalR-samples/tree/main/aspnet-samples/AdvancedChatRoom).

Refer this [Azure SignalR Messaging With .Net Core Console App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-signalr-messaging-with-net-core-console-app-server-and-client/) which explains the Azure Signal R configuration in `ASP.Net Core` and same can be implemented in MVC Application based on your requirement.